# How do I turn my T-SQL single column unpivot statement to a multi-column unpivot statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I working with T-SQL and currently have a single column pivot that I'm trying to convert into a multi-column pivot.    My current SQL follows:

```
    SELECT T_CODE, TYPE, P_VALUE
    FROM POC s
    unpivot
    (P_VALUE
    FOR TYPE IN (P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4, P_5, P_6, LA_1, LA_2, LA_3, LA_4, LA_5, LA_6, LB_1, LB_2, LB_3, LB_4, LB_5, LB_6)) u
```

This produces a table with the following structure, where the type column can include one of 18 values P_1-P_6, LA_1-LA_6 and LB_1-LB_6:

```
T_Code     Type     P_Value
123         P_1        1
123         LA_1       2
123         LB_1       2
...         ...        --
```

What I would like to do, however is have a table that the following structure:

```
T_Code     P     LA   LB  
 123       1      2    2
```

As I was researching this online, I came across this great [Zen SQL blog post](http://pratchev.blogspot.com/2009/02/unpivoting-multiple-columns.html) that I thought provided me a viable solution, but I'm not quite able to get it to work.

My data structure is a bit different than the example because my Type column includes three different types of data so this is what I thought might work. Unfortunately, it does not.  Can anyone point me in the right direction.

```
    SELECT R_DATE, TYPE, P_VALUE
        FROM POC s
        unpivot
        (P_VALUE
        FOR TYPE IN (P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4, P_5, P_6)) u1
        unpivot
        (P_VALUE
        FOR TYPE IN (LA_1, LA_2, LA_3, LA_4, LA_5, LA_6)) u2
        unpivot
        (P_VALUE
        FOR TYPE IN (LA_6, LB_1, LB_2, LB_3, LB_4, LB_5, LB_6)) u3
```

Here is some sample data:

```
T_Code     Type     P_Value
123        P_1       1
123        P_2       4
123        P_3       1
123        P_4       2
123        P_5       5
123        P_6       1
123        LA_1       1
123        LA_2       2
123        LA_3       1
123        LA_4       6
123        LA_5       1
123        LA_6       5
123        LB_1       1
123        LB_2       1
123        LB_3       1
123        LB_4       4
123        LB_5       9
123        LB_6       1
```

Comment: Prepare initial structures and data in http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Can you post sample data for `POC` table? SQL fiddle would also be great to troubleshoot.

Comment: Also you are showing R_DATE in your select statement but your output shows T_CODE. Are those two fields are same or in your sql incomplete?

Comment: I corrected the R_DATE typo. Thanks. I will also post some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to use a case expression:

```
select
     T_CODE,
     sum(case when Type like 'P_%'  then P_VALUE else null end) as P,
     sum(case when Type like 'LA_%' then P_VALUE else null end) as LA,
     sum(case when Type like 'LB_%' then P_VALUE else null end) as LB
from POC
group by T_CODE;
```

If you really feel the need to use pivot operations, I think you want `pivot` rather than `unpivot`:

```
select T_CODE, [P], [LA], [LB]
from
    (
        select T_CODE, substring(TYPE, 1, charindex('_', TYPE) - 1) as BUCKET, P_VALUE
        from POC
    ) as data
    pivot
    (
        sum(P_VALUE)
        for BUCKET IN ([P], [LA], [LB])
    ) as pvt;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f7be/9)